# Is it possible to restrict a gradle repository to a particular configuration?

Tags: gradle, repository

I want to tie gradle repositories to specific configurations in my `build.gradle` file, e.g.:

```
repositories {
    testCompile {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    compile {
        maven { url 'https://vetted-repo.example.com' }
    }
}
```

I can't find a simple way to do this from the gradle documentation.  Do I need to write my own plugin?

Comment: As far as I know this is not supported out-of-the-box and You need to implement a custom solution.

Answer (score 5):

As of Gradle 5.1 this is now possible, from the [release notes](https://docs.gradle.org/5.1/release-notes.html#repository-to-dependency-matching):

> It is now possible to match repositories to dependencies, so that
> Gradle doesn't search for a dependency in a repository if it's never
> going to be found there.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> repositories {
>   maven {
>     url "https://repo.mycompany.com"
>     content {
>       includeGroupByRegex "com\\.mycompany.*"
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

For the specific requirement of restricting a repository to a specific configuration such as `compile`, you could use the `onlyForConfigurations` property:

```
repositories {
  maven { 
    url "https://vetted-repo.example.com"
    content {
      onlyForConfigurations "compile"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As far as understand the question, this is an off-topic answer. He wants to be able to restrict dependency repository based on current gradle configurations, not on dependency itself. For example we could want to restrict compilation to a limited but known local repository, but for testCompilation allow all maven-central for more flexibility in test which are less critical.

Comment: This is possible using https://docs.gradle.org/5.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/repositories/RepositoryContentDescriptor.html#onlyForConfigurations(java.lang.String...), I've updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported by gradle at the moment. When resolving dependencies, gradle tries al listed repositories (from top to bottom) to resolve a dependency. Once the dependency is found it stops looking for it in other repositories

Comment: Is it still the case at the moment (e.g. Gradle 2.13+)

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to declare a repository filter in gradle. see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#declaring_a_repository_filter this does exactly what you need here.